# How to use Accumulator correctly in Spark to get right answer?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, accumulator

I am new in scala and spark. I want to use Accumulators in spark inside a function to increment as the function is called by a map function.

I have an RDD that its name is `vertices` and each row of RDD has a tuple2, ID and its property(key,value), for example:

```
(1,1)
(2,1)
.
.
.
(34,1)
```

I want to use accumulator to be incremented when the key % 2 is equal to zero. If it is equal to zero, accumulator will be incremented by 1 and we will have a tuple2 with key equal to ID and value will be accumulator that is incremented and if the key % 2 is not equal to zero, we will have a tuple2 with key equal to ID and value equal to last accumulator value.

```
val label_counter = sc.accumulator(0,"label_counter")  

def do_someThing (vertex:VertexId): (VertexId, Accumulator[Int]) = {
    if (vertex % 2 == 0) {
        label_counter +=1
        return (vertex,label_counter)
    } else return (vertex, label_counter)
}

val accum_test = vertices.map(x => (x._1)).map(do_someThing )
accum_test.foreach(println)
```

in this case the result is something like this:

```
 (2,1)
 (13,1)
 (19,1)
 (34,2)
 (15,2)
 (4,3)
 .....
```

This result is what I expect. The key is a node ID and the value is accumulator value in each map call.

but instead of the last line of code, when i use `accum_test.collect().foreach(println)` the result looks like this:

```
 (2,17)
 (13,17)
 (19,17)
 (34,17)
 (15,17)
 (4,17)
 ....
```

in this case when i use collect , the value part of tuple2 is all 17. its the last value that accumulator takes. and i dont expect this answer

i dont know why this happens and where is the mistake?? how should i write this code in correct way??. i thinks i have some problem with accumulator concept.

i have another question. the nodes that are not ordered, for example 2,13,19,34,15,4 and ... means that these numbers are distributed on different executors?? and distributing them made them to become unordered?? because they are ordered number in the text file.

please help me with these problems. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using accumulators for something they are not meant for. Accumulators are meant to accumulate something over the RDD and get that accumulation back to the driver. The value is not meant to be used within the executors, and the result when you do it is not defined, which is why you get different result depending on seemingly unrelated details. Keep in mind that RDDs are distributed and the accumulation is run in parallel on the various partitions. This is why the result of accessing the value within the executors is unexpected.

To illustrate what I was saying before. The correct use case just is:

```scala
vertices.foreach(do_something) // accumulating
println(label_counter.value) // result on the driver
```

Comment: actually i am working on a graph for community detection and i want to give labels to nodes based on some computations, so i should not use accumulators for the label variable???   for example our labels start from 0 and when a node gets label, the label counter should be incremented and other nodes then will get the new incremented  label and so on. what should i do with this?? i mean what kind of variable should i use for storing label and incrementing it to be used in propagating label to other nodes??

Comment: Are you asking how you could get the result you expected in your question, or is it something different?

Comment: its a little different but its related to the example i wrote. for example we have some nodes that their initial label is all 0. in iterations and based on some conditions nodes get new label. as nodes get label, the label counter should be increment for other nodes.  for example we have 3 nodes  ```(1,0),(2,0),(3,0) ``` node 1 updates its label and becomes ```(1,1)``` first number is node ID and second one is label. then label increments and node 2 doesnt get new label and node 3 gets label and becomes ```(3,2)``` . my question is that what kind of variable should i use? is Accumulator ok ?

Comment: i mean because nodes in RDD are distributed among executors, and they update their label, is it ok to use Accumulator for storing label counter in each iterations and use it in next step itterations?? because if i use variable other than accumulator it will be updated in one executor but other executors wont be notified of new value of label counter. in this situation should i use accumulator as the label counter variable or there is other way to handle this??

Comment: It is quite hard to get a good understanding of what you are trying to do without code and data. Could you post a new question with as much detail as you can provide and post the link here? I'll look into it.

Comment: this link is for the new question i asked about my problem   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57733691/what-kind-of-variable-select-for-incrementing-node-labels-in-a-community-detecti