# What kind of variable select for incrementing node labels in a community detection algorithm

Tags: scala, apache-spark, graph, spark-graphx

i am working on a community detection algorithm that uses the concept of propagating label to nodes. i have problem in selecting the true type for the `Label_counter` variable.

we have an algorithm with name `LPA(label propagation algorithm)` which propagates labels to nodes through iterations. think labels as node property. the initial label for each node is the node id, and in iterations nodes update their new label based on the most frequent label among its neighbors. the algorithm i am working on is something like LPA. at first every node has initial label equal to 0 and then nodes get new labels. as nodes update and get new labels, based on some conditions the `Label_counter` should be incremented by one to use this value as label for other nodes . for example label=1 or label = 2 and so on. for example we have zachary karate club dataset that it has 34 nodes and the dataset has 2 communities. 
the initial state is like this:

```
 (1,0)
 (2,0)
   .
   .
   .
 (34,0)
```

first number is node Id and second one is label.
as nodes get new label, the `Label_counter` increments and other nodes in next iterations get new label and again `Label_counter` increments.

```
 (1,1)
 (2,1)
 (3,1)
   .
   .
   .
 (33,3)
 (34,3)
```

nodes with same label, belong to same community.

the problem that i have is: 
because nodes in RDD and variables are distributed across the machines(each machine has a copy of variables) and executors dont have connection with each other, if an executor updates the `Label_counter`, other executors wont be informed of new value of `Label_counter` and  maybe nodes will get wrong labels, IS it true to use `Accumulator` as label counter in this case, because Accumulators are shared variables across machines, or there is other ways for handling this problem???

Answer (score 0):

In spark it is always complicated to compute index like values because they depend on things that are not in all the partitions. I can propose the following idea.

1. Compute the number of time the condition is met per partition
2. Compute the cumulated increment per partition so that we know the initial increment of each partition.
3. Increment the values of the partition based on that initial increment

Here is what the code could look like this. Let me start by setting up a few things.

```scala
// Let's define some condition
def condition(node : Long) = node % 10 == 1

// step 0, generate the data
val rdd = spark.range(34)
    .select('id+1).repartition(10).rdd
    .map(r => (r.getAs[Long](0), 0))
    .sortBy(_._1).cache()
rdd.collect
Array[(Long, Int)] = Array((1,0), (2,0), (3,0), (4,0), (5,0), (6,0), (7,0), (8,0),
 (9,0), (10,0), (11,0), (12,0), (13,0), (14,0), (15,0), (16,0), (17,0), (18,0),
 (19,0), (20,0), (21,0), (22,0), (23,0), (24,0), (25,0), (26,0), (27,0), (28,0),
 (29,0), (30,0), (31,0), (32,0), (33,0), (34,0))
```

Then the core of the solution:

```scala
// step 1 and 2
val partIncrInit = rdd
    // to each partition, we associate the number of times we need to increment
    .mapPartitionsWithIndex{ case (i,p) =>
        Iterator(i -> p.map(_._1).count(condition))
    }
    .collect.sorted // sort by partition index
    .map(_._2) // we don't need the index anymore
    .scanLeft(0)(_+_) // cumulated sum

// step 3, we increment each partition based on this initial increment.
val result = rdd
    .mapPartitionsWithIndex{ case (i, p) =>
        var incr = 0
        p.map{ case (node, value) =>
            if(condition(node))
                incr+=1
            (node, partIncrInit(i) + value + incr) 
        }
    }
result.collect

Array[(Long, Int)] = Array((1,1), (2,1), (3,1), (4,1), (5,1), (6,1), (7,1), (8,1),
 (9,1), (10,1), (11,2), (12,2), (13,2), (14,2), (15,2), (16,2), (17,2), (18,2),
 (19,2), (20,2), (21,3), (22,3), (23,3), (24,3), (25,3), (26,3), (27,3), (28,3),
 (29,3), (30,3), (31,4), (32,4), (33,4), (34,4))
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. i understand what you mean, its not the exact thing i was looking for. but it gave me new idea. i should check it on my code. thanks for time you spent on helping

Comment: Can I ask what you were looking for?

Comment: i mean incrementing ```label_counter``` is not based on number of conditions met on one partition, for example maybe ```label_counter``` doesn't update for some iteration and after that it increments and we need the ```label_counter``` from previous iteration. i mean its not like that nodes that are in one partition get same label, its an iterative algorithm that for example a node updates its label and we should propagate that label to its neighbors. we need that value every time to give to other nodes.

Comment: for example  maybe one node is on one partition and other neighbor is in other partition and based on some condition this two nodes should get same label. i need that value to be ready every time to give to nodes. label_counter is independent from partition. we do some computation and update label_counter and propagate it to other neighbors. label_counter should be ready to give to every node in any partition that the condition for it is true